# Why do (hidden) markov models have strong predictive power?

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model

(Hidden) markov models predict the next future state only dependent on the current state. I would not expect any algorithm that is only considering the present state to have a lot of predictive power. Yet, they are widely used. I guess I am missing something, but what?

Comment: This seems mostly a matter of psychology, so let's ask about your awareness: have you considered that a "state" can be a very rich and complex thing?  For instance, the state of an evolving system, for the purposes of modeling, may include not only the variables that describe it *now*, but it may also include the variables that describe it at a fixed number of times in the past.  Another way to help the intuition is to recognize that the fundamental equations of classical physics--Newton's Laws--are completely Markovian: the evolution of a physical system is determined by its present state.

Comment: @whuber: Good points, thanks. Physics however depends no only on a discrete number of states, but on a lot of "features" that are continuous. Doesn't that make quite the difference?

Comment: Not at all.  The mathematics gets a little more involved when there is a continuum of states, but the concepts don't change.  And I think you might underestimate the scope of physical theory.  The classical formulations of mechanics (as well as non-relativistic quantum mechanics), for instance, characterize a physical state in terms of a vector of (continuous) position and momentum coordinates. The equations of motion are just a vector field within this [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space_(physics)).

Comment: @whuber: I am not sure how this disagrees with what I wrote: Sure I can say that speed, weight, form etc. of an object flying in space are all together just a single state. But each of these physical properties is on a continuous scale. I don't see how I would represent this in a hidden markov model, except with an infinite amount of hidden states.

Comment: @Make42 You're right, you can't. In order to predict exactly what's going to happen to an object flying in space, you need to use physics, not a HMM. Even a time-based model with continuous latent variables (like a Linear Dynamical System or Recurrent Neural Network) might approximate it better than a HMM, but there's no reason to use them if you understand the physics well enough to do the exact calculation. Also these methods only consider time in discrete steps, you need to use continuous time to be more exact about the motion of objects.

Comment: Your question seems fundamentally about the Markov property rather than hidden Markov models in particular.  That, at least, is how I understood the meaning of your parentheses around "hidden."  Moreover, there is no essential conceptual distinction between a continuous and discrete state model, since the continuous-state model can be discretized to a good approximation.

Comment: Let's add that first-order HMM only consider the current space for transiting to the next, but that it exists higher orders that extend this dependence to more time steps. It all depends on what you want to predict. For instance, the next word in a sentence mostly depends on the previous word (or the few previous ones).

Comment: @Eskapp: I never heard of higher order HMM. Can you point to literature?

Comment: One example of second-order HMM: http://acl-arc.comp.nus.edu.sg/archives/acl-arc-090501d4/data/pdf/anthology-PDF/P/P99/P99-1023.pdf
More generally about Markov chain, if you look online for `n-th order Markov chain`, you will find many resources.